# does it make sense to use datagridview just for one record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

If I need to show some info on the page and use lot of labels for this, does it make sense to use datagridview and show info as one record?

Comment: Not to me, but I guess that's subjective.

Comment: It works. So it's your wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to depend heavily on the specifics of your situation. If the tablized view of the data is perfect for your situation, then it might make perfect sense. On the other hand, you allow a lot more formatting adjustments and specificity if you use labels and divs and the like to support more detailed css.

Comment: I just tired of using these divs, because tables is prohibited now.

Answer (score 2):

A [`FormView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf1dk77%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is more recommended in such cases. It's a control that displays data for a single record. In the end of the day whichever control you use will work, but `FormView` makes it easier to format the data you want to display (in this specific case).

Comment: maybe FormView is better, I didn't think about it, because we use datagridview almost on each page.

Comment: but maybe DetailsView?

Comment: @Alex That's up to you. You should experiment with those controls to find which suits you best. That's actually a good thing to do... By getting acquainted with all of the data controls, you'll make better, faster decisions about which one to use in each situation.